# ReSharper intellisense for netcoreapp2.0 console app referencing netstandard2.0 lib

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.0, .net-standard-2.0

I installed visual studio 15.3 and the .net core 2.0 sdk today.  I created a console application(netcoreapp2.0) with a project reference to a library(netstandard2.0).  With ReSharper enabled I'm not getting any intellisense for types in the library.  Lot's of errors in VS but the project builds/runs if done from the command line(dotnet build).  If I suspend ReSharper, intellisense starts working.  With ReSharper enabled, if I set the library to netstandard1.x intellisense works.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper 2017.1 doesn't support the final versions of .net core 2 or .net standard 2 - it was released before they were. There is better support in the current (as of 16/08/2017) [EAP builds of 2017.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/eap/), but there are still some issues. We'll be improving the support for the rest of the Early Access Program, and be ready for the release of ReSharper 2017.2, which should be very soon.

Answer (score -1):

For now, if you can, change your library project from netstandard2.0 to netcoreapp2.0.

`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>`

It will work just fine :)